# getopt implicit declaration in Solaris?

Tags: c, unix, gcc, solaris, posix

In Solaris, gcc gives me

> implicit declaration of function `getopt'

when compiling

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    getopt(1,argv,"");
    return 0;
}
```

The [man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/821-1465/getopt-3c.html#scrolltoc) for getopt says something about including unistd.h or stdio.h, however even though I'm inluding both I still get this warning. Is this normal? Is using functions that aren't explicitly declared common in Unix development?

Comment: I'm compiling with gcc -ansi -pedantic -Wall

Comment: @Steven What does "grep getopt /usr/include/*.h" return?

Answer (score 9):

You're compiling with `-ansi`, and in that mode `getopt` might not be available, since `-ansi` implies C89 conformant mode.  Try removing that switch, or `#define _GNU_SOURCE` before `#include <unistd.h>`.  `getopt()` is POSIX, not ANSI.

*Edit*: You probably don't need `_GNU_SOURCE`.  According to [this](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getopt.3.html), you should be able to get the functionality with defining preprocessor macros such that this is true:

```
#if _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 2 || _XOPEN_SOURCE || _POSIX_SOURCE
```

See [this](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02_01_01) for more information on the feature test macros.

Comment: removing -ansi does indeed remove the warning. However, I wonder why getopt() is not C89 conformant when every other POSIX function I've used didn't give any warnings
#define _GNU_SOURCE doesn't though (this is Solaris)

Comment: See my edit.  C89 doesn't define getopt: so it would be wrong for glibc to expose it when compiling in C89 mode.  Although, since it's declared in unistd.h, which doesn't exist in C89, maybe glibc can do this, I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

The man page says to include `stdio.h`, not `stdlib.h`. Does including `stdio.h` fix the problem?

Comment: Instead of --ansi, and provided you want to be explicit about the standard, -std=standard can be used. For eg: -std=gnu90 compiles w/o any warnings and is the default setting at the moment (when -std is omitted).

Answer (score 1):

Using gnu99 solved it for me:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 file.c
```

This is with `unistd.h`.